# Некоректное отображение иконки GIMP

Tags: linux, kubuntu

В чем суть проблемы: скачал и установил GIMP на Kubuntu 19.04, пока приложение не открыто, иконки нету, а как только открывается, иконка появляется в плохом разрешении. Пробовал менять иконку вручну, переписывая путь к иконке в .desktop файле, но все равно, в меню приложений иконка есть, в док-панеле ее нету, а при открытом приложении все еще иконка с плохим разрешением.

Comment: KUbuntu - это версия с KDE? И с плазмой?

Comment: Да. KDE Plasma 5.